# How do I revert in case of wrong option?

Tags: shell

```
select_again_dir:
echo -e "\033[32m enter the name of the source file; \033[0m"
echo
ls
echo
read build_source_dir

if [ ! -d $build_source_dir ]
then
    echo "Folder Not Found. Please select again;"
    goto select_again_dir:
else
    echo "folder exists"
fi
```

Hello,
If the source file cannot be found, I want it to re-enter a value.

Is there a function you can suggest instead of goto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is a while loop. One way to avoid duplication of the input read:

```
echo -e "\033[32m enter the name of the source file; \033[0m"
while [ ! -d "$build_source_dir" ]; do
    echo
    ls
    echo
    read build_source_dir
    echo "Folder Not Found. Please select again: "        
done
echo "folder exists"
```

Comment: If `build_source_dir` is unset or empty, then `[ ! -d $build_source_dir ]` will fail and the loop will never execute.

Comment: thank you my problem is solved. I would like to ask one more thing, is it possible to list the folders and have them selected directly?

Comment: @arcface I don't have time right now. Please ask a different questions for that and list it here in the comments. I will have a look later.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop it. You can use `break` and `continue` to your favor.

```
while true; do
  echo -e "\033[32m enter the name of the source file; \033[0m"
  echo
  ls
  echo
  read build_source_dir

  if [ ! -d "$build_source_dir" ]
  then
    echo "Folder Not Found. Please select again;"
    continue   # not really needed, there is nothing below to happen
  else
    echo "folder exists"
    break      # jump out of the loop
  fi
done
```

Comment: thank you my problem is solved. I would like to ask one more thing, is it possible to list the folders and have them selected directly?